# css unwanted white block

Tags: html, css

I try to build a blue thing centered and on top of a background. But somehow, I got the unwanted white thing.

The white thing is from the my `main`. It's in the space where `main` shifts `top: 5vh` and `left: 5vh`.

```css
:root {
  --red: rgb(218, 39, 39);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bg div {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--red);
  left: 50%;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vh;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </section>
  </main>

  <div class="bg">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the "white" background where you've rounded the border? Consider applying padding to your content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --red: rgb(218, 39, 39);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.bg div {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg div:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg div:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--red);
  left: 50%;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5vh;
  left: 5vh;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>Text</h1>
    </section>
  </main>

  <div class="bg">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You simply need to position your "background" so it start at the top left corner.

Comment: OMG you have solved my problem!! thank you so much!